# Newbee Question: Attempting to install Ubuntu server + Unity to get a GUI of server configuration

Tags: unity, server, configuration

My objective is to get a graphical desktop of the Ubuntu server services (Apache, SQL, DCHP and similar services).  Ideally I should be able to configure these services through a GUI.

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 with AMP options.  I have also installed the Unit-Desktop.  It appears that when i installed the `ubuntu-desktop` but now it just looks like a `ubuntu-desktop` system.

At some point I will learn all of the cli but in the interim I am trying to get some things running quickly.

Any assistance is appreciated.
Mark

Comment: Please be more specific. It is not clear from your question what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ubuntu-desktop package should take care of all the dependencies, is that the one you installed? If not:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I don't know exactly what you mean by "it looks like a ubuntu-desktop system" but if you meant it looks like the old gnome2 desktop, maybe the problem is you need to install the drivers for your graphic card, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, a question right up my ally.

I highly suggest install webmin on your unit. Assuming you have already installed a LAMP server, here are some instructions.

1 Download the latest webmin from [here](http://www.webmin.com/download.html) (1.660 when this was made)

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.660_all.deb
```

2 Install webmin

```
dpkg --install webmin_1.660_all.deb
```

3 (optional) If you get any errors...

```
apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
```

4 open port 10000 in your firewall

```
cd /var/lib
nano iptables
```

5 add lines to config

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

6 you can now log in to webmin!

```
http://systemip:10000/
```

7 enjoy!

If you are looking for a GUI to put directly on the system, see the ink below.

Hope this helped!

---

"http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html"